# How to open remote desktop in a script, which runs as windows task?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to import data from a remote server. My current approach is the create a script on the remote server, which is executed every time I log in using remote desktop. When I log in, a network share is mounted into the RDP session, and the script which is executed, copies a directory from the remote server to the mounted network share, thus making this directory locally available.

I want to automate this process, by creating a windows task. This task should log in a user in the remote server (RDP), and thus trigger the script execution. Is this a feasible method? Would it be possible to achieve this in another way?

Comment: How do you plan to store the credentials needed to make a connection? What privileges do those credentials have on the remote machine?

Comment: I would create an `remote.rdp` file, and launch it from the script with the credentials saved. The user logging into the remove machine has enough right to execute `xcopy`and put the file into the mounted share.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a workaround? I would make it possible to connect to the other pc directly through a network share (in combination with VPN if required). Or use FTP if VPN is not available.

Comment: The connection is established by VPN, and only port 3389 is allowed to be open in the firewall...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can write a powershell script to do the needful and from task scheduler by adding action as "Program/Script: Powershell.exe" and argument should me your ps file location. Check the [Microsoft](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx) link for detailed information on how to execute a powershell script in task scheduler.

Edited:

You can connect remote machine from poweshell using the command

> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName computer_name

[Steps to establish remote connection using power shell.](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/creating-remote-sessions-powershell-20)

Comment: Running the powershell script as a task is the easier part. I am trying to open RDP session using the script, or looking for an alternative approach.

Comment: @Kiril, the post has been updated :)

Comment: This is a really nice approach. I have to check whether the remote server can enable WinRM. Thanks.